# map specific offices within range

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, maps, geospatial, bing-maps

We have a requirement to find corporate offices within a certain distance of a zip code

Requirements:
Can be a spreadsheet or web app, something portable.
We have a master office list with different office type categories.

Users need to be able to upload or populate a second list with customer addresses or just zip codes, sometimes up to 15000 at a time, they then need to be able to select a distance (e.g. 10 Miles, 25 Miles etc) and then select one or multiple office categories to display the results of offices within the selected mileage range, is there something already available to do this or does someone have an example?

Thanks ahead

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a store locator, but instead of stores you have corporate offices. Here is a step by step guide on how to create a store locator using Bing Maps: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn948092.aspx

Comment: This is not quite what I need, I need a bulk calculation and output showing locations with in the specified ranges where available

Comment: This does that. If you load your data into the Bing Spatial Data Services you can then specify the search radius. Alternatively, if you simply want to filter the data based on distance, this can be done right in code using the Haversine formula.